# Creating threads fails with “Resource temporarily unavailable” with 4.3 kernel

Tags: linux, docker, limit, fork, thread

I am running a docker server on Arch Linux (kernel 4.3.3-2) with several containers. Since my last reboot, both the docker server and random programs within the containers crash with a message about not being able to create a thread, or (less often) to fork. The specific error message is different depending on the program, but most of them seem to mention the specific error `Resource temporarily unavailable`. See at the end of this post for some example error messages.

Now there are plenty of people who have had this error message, and plenty of responses to them. What’s really frustrating is that everyone seems to be speculating how the issue could be resolved, but no one seems to point out how to *identify* which of the many possible causes for the problem is present.

I have collected these 5 possible causes for the error and how to verify that they are not present on my system:

1. There is a system-wide limit on the number of threads configured in `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22570554/242365)). In my case this is set to `60613`.
2. Every thread takes some space in the stack. The stack size limit is configured using `ulimit -s` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9211891/242365)). The limit for my shell used to be `8192`, but I have increased it by putting `* soft stack 32768` into `/etc/security/limits.conf`, so it `ulimit -s` now returns `32768`. I have also increased it for the docker process by putting `LimitSTACK=33554432` into `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` ([source](https://sskaje.me/systemd-ulimit/), and I verified that the limit applies by looking into `/proc/<pid of docker>/limits` and by running `ulimit -s` inside a docker container.
3. Every thread takes some memory. A virtual memory limit is configured using `ulimit -v`. On my system it is set to `unlimited`, and 80% of my 3 GB of memory are free.
4. There is a limit on the number of processes using `ulimit -u`. Threads count as processes in this case ([source](https://superuser.com/a/568943/23403)). On my system, the limit is set to `30306`, and for the docker daemon and inside docker containers, the limit is `1048576`. The number of currently running threads can be found out by running `ls -1d /proc/*/task/* | wc -l` or by running `ps -elfT | wc -l` ([source](http://rudametw.github.io/blog/posts/2014.04.10/not-enough-threads.html)). On my system they are between `700` and `800`.
5. There is a limit on the number of open files, which according to some [source](http://dimitrik.free.fr/blog/archives/2010/11/mysql-performance-hitting-error-cant-create-a-new-thread-errno-11-on-a-high-number-of-connections.html)s is also relevant when creating threads. The limit is configured using `ulimit -n`. On my system and inside docker, the limit is set to `1048576`. The number of open files can be found out using `lsof | wc -l` ([source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html)), on my system it is about `30000`.

It looks like before the last reboot I was running kernel 4.2.5-1, now I’m running 4.3.3-2. Downgrading to 4.2.5-1 fixes all the problems. Other posts mentioning the problem are [this](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/11/24/203) and [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1593364). I have opened a [bug report for Arch Linux](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47662).

What has changed in the kernel that could be causing this?

---

Here are some example error messages:

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Failed to create aux thread
```

```
Jan 07 14:37:25 edeltraud docker[30625]: runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 fork failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

```
test -z "/usr/include" || /usr/sbin/mkdir -p "/tmp/lib32-popt/pkg/lib32-popt/usr/include"
/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 popt.h '/tmp/lib32-popt/pkg/lib32-popt/usr/include'
test -z "/usr/share/man/man3" || /usr/sbin/mkdir -p "/tmp/lib32-popt/pkg/lib32-popt/usr/share/man/man3"
/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/bin/sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/bin/sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/bin/sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/bin/sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/bin/sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/bin/sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
make[3]: *** [install-man3] Error 254
```

```
Jan 07 11:04:39 edeltraud docker[780]: time="2016-01-07T11:04:39.986684617+01:00" level=error msg="Error running container: [8] System error: fork/exec /proc/self/exe: resource temporarily unavailable"
```

```
[Wed Jan 06 23:20:33.701287 2016] [mpm_event:alert] [pid 217:tid 140325422335744] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
```

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to the 4.3 kernel?

Comment: That’s very well possible. Why?

Comment: Amazing, I downgraded to kernel 4.2.5-1 and everything is working again! Do you have any clue what is causing this and how to fix it with 4.3?

Comment: No clue what's causing it. My method of fixing it is waiting for the Arch Linux forum threads on the topic to be marked "SOLVED" :-P.

Comment: So how did you guess it? Did you come across similar problems?

Comment: Sadly, I'm having the exact same problem (plus, Chrome no longer plays youtube videos - not sure if that's related) and found your SE question. [This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207255) was just started today and describes the same problem, along with the solution of downgrading to 4.2.5.

Comment: Interestingly, after downgrading to 4.2.5 myself, Chrome is behaving well again. Now if only I could find VirtualBox packages for arch that are compatible with this kernel...

Comment: Funny that I am running 4.3.3-2 on my desktop computer and I have Chromium open with more than 100 tabs without a problem.

Comment: [The behaviour is not in fact specific to Arch or to Docker, but is exhibited in a *lot* of things](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11675133).  There is an open systemd bug about that at the time that I write this.

Comment: +1 For being an excellently asked and researched question, even if I _didn't_ have the same problem

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem is caused by the [`TasksMax`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#TasksMax=N) systemd attribute. It was introduced in systemd 228 and makes use of the cgroups pid subsystem, which was introduced in the linux kernel 4.3. A task limit of `512` is thus enabled in systemd if kernel 4.3 or newer is running. The feature is announced [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/ddb4b0d3eb57292c38a76f9b977f73cea15448fb/NEWS#L65) and was introduced in [this pull request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/1239) and the default values were set by [this pull request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/1886). After upgrading my kernel to 4.3, `systemctl status docker` displays a `Tasks` line:

```
# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-01-15 19:58:00 CET; 1min 52s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 2770 (docker)
    Tasks: 502 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
```

Setting `TasksMax=infinity` in the `[Service]` section of `docker.service` fixes the problem. `docker.service` is usually in `/usr/share/systemd/system`, but it can also be put/copied in `/etc/systemd/system` to avoid it being overridden by the package manager.

A [pull request](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19391) is increasing `TasksMax` for the docker example systemd files, and an [Arch Linux bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47872) is trying to achieve the same for the package. There is some additional discussion going on [on the Arch Linux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207255) and [in an Arch Linux bug report regarding lxc](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47303).

[`DefaultTasksMax`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#DefaultTasksMax=) can be used in the `[Manager]` section in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` (or `/etc/systemd/user.conf` for user-run services) to control the default value for `TasksMax`.

Systemd also applies a limit for programs run from a login-shell. These default to `4096` per user (will be [increased to `12288`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2388)) and are configured as [`UserTasksMax`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#UserTasksMax=) in the `[Login]` section of `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

Comment: FWIW, the service file was at `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` in my Debian testing.

Comment: FWIW, saying `systemctl set-property docker.service TasksMax=4096` will set the property for a currently running service and persist the setting for subsequent reboots in the correct place for the docker installation in question.

Comment: [This is a common approach](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11675133).  But note that the Docker change that you proposed was reverted after you posted this answer, on 2016-02-09, this reversion being then released to the world in Docker version 1.10.1.

Comment: man thanks thanks thanks ! i have been looking for tooooo long for this

Comment: If you make the change to the config file (mine was in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/50-TasksMax.conf` on Ubuntu 16), you need to run `systemctl daemon-reload`. Doing a `sudo service docker restart` will NOT work.

Comment: thanks, this helped me with my apache being limited

Answer (score 7):

cdauth's answer is correct, but there is another detail to add.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 system with systemd 229 and a 4.3 kernel, a 512 pid limit was enforced on session scopes by default even when UserTasksMax was set to the new, increased default of 12288.  So any user session scope was limited to 512 threads.

The only way I found to remove the limit was to set `DefaultTasksMax=unlimited` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `systemctl daemon-reexec` (or reboot).

You can check if this is happening by issuing `systemctl status`, picking a session scope, and `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-${UID}.slice/session-FOO.scope/pids.max`.

Comment: I made the change to /etc/systemd/system.conf and rebooted. Docker still lists the limit on tasks as 512. Using @Nakedible's comment from above did update the available tasks.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! @BenMathews perhaps this was because **both** are valid issues on Ubuntu 16.04, you need to fix them **both** for things to work properly. This issue appears to apply to containers started by a daemon, not by a user in a shell. So everything appears fine, you add `@reboot lxc-autostart` to your crontab to autostart them on boot, and you suddenly get crippled containers after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16256) thread.

This solution worked for me: `docker -d --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs`. I actually added it to the `OPTIONS` in `/etc/sysconfig/docker`...

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> [3178:4:0817/094911.485035:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(155)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
> ```

I was able to resolve this issue in `podman run` using `--pids-limit=-1` argument